# assigning icon value based on data from flutter sqflite

Tags: flutter, sqflite, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm trying to load the favorite button on my card based on the data from database inside the future builder. while using the following code inside ListView.Builder, is sets the value to true and button click does not change it. I think it is because of FutureBuilder.

```
txtData.zFavourite == null
                    ? isFavourite[index] = false
                    : isFavourite[index] = true;
```

it also requires to initialize the value for isFavourite and if it is assigned outside the widget, I do not get the data from database as it directly loads into the future builder.
how do we assign the value for isFavourite based on the data from the database and change the favourite icon based on the button click?

I also [checked this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65652055/flutter-how-do-i-add-favorites-inside-a-listview-builder) to handle button clicks for the individual list.

```
late List<bool> isFavourite = [false, false];
Widget _displayZhesa() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Zhebsa>>(
        future: _getZhebsa(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final txtData = snapshot.data![index];
                txtData.zFavourite == null
                    ? isFavourite[index] = false
                    : isFavourite[index] = true;
                return Card(
                  elevation: 10,
                  color: Colors.white70,
                  shadowColor: Colors.amber[500],
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        width: double.infinity,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.orange[400],
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.amber.shade100,
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            sQuery,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Center(
                            child: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  isFavourite[index] = !isFavourite[index];
                                });
                              },
                              /* () =>
                                  _setFaviurite(txtData.zFavourite, index), */
                              icon: Icon(
                                isFavourite[index]
                                    ? Icons.favorite_sharp
                                    : Icons.favorite_border_sharp,
                                size: 30.0,
                                color: Colors.redAccent,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: const Text('ཞེ་ས།'),
                              subtitle: Text(txtData.zWord), //ཞེ་སའི་ཚིག
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                            child: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                isPlayingPronunciation
                                    ? stopPronunciation()
                                    : _playPronunciation(
                                        '${txtData.zPronunciation}');
                                setState(() {
                                  isPlayingPronunciation =
                                      !isPlayingPronunciation;
                                });
                              },
                              icon: Icon(
                                isPlayingPronunciation
                                    ? Icons.stop_circle_outlined
                                    : Icons.volume_up,
                                size: 50.0,
                                color: Colors.blue,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: const Text('དཔེར་བརྗོད།'),
                          subtitle: SelectableText('${txtData.zPhrase}'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            return const Text('No Data');
          }
        });
  }
```

Comment: I prefer not using `FutureBuilder` while i need to call setState, instead init data on `initState` or `StreamBuilder`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51983011/10157127) might help you

Comment: thank you. As I am not familiar with StreamBuilder, I populated all the data in the initState and then returned return ListView.builder inside the widget. It worked.